# Geolocalisation based on gps or gprs(ip)

Tags: java, android, geolocation, ip-geolocation

please i wish to know which method of motion detection is best for an dndroid application using GPS OR GPRS( Triangulation) for faster and better info manipilation for a particular state only. if any help links available i will be thankfull.

Answer (score 0):

Both GPS and GSM has its own pros and cons.

GPS is more accurate compare to GSM cell tower ID. It works for non-SIM device such as iPad etcs.

However, GPS is not available or enabled in all devices. GSM connections are almost available in all phone devices with SIM card and use less power the GPS.